# I want to get package from text

Tags: java, android, regex

I have two textview1 and textview2 and one button1 and the textview1 contains a package for example, "com.package.name" and I want to get that package name from textview1 and show it in textview2 and I think I can take it using regex but I don't know how to use regex

One more thing that the package in textview1 could be change please help me it's my second time that I am asking the same question

textview1 look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: just use `getText()` of one textview and assign it in other one. Why are you going in regex? 
If you want, you use String methods and use the matchers to match your preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method will retrieve **package** from an XML String as your textView1 has, use below method to get Package

**Java**

```
String getPackageNameFromXml(String s) {
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
        myParser.setInput(new StringReader(s));
        int event = myParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name = myParser.getName();
            switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: {
                    if (name.toLowerCase().equals("manifest")) {
                        String packageName = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "package");
                        if (packageName != null) {
                            return packageName;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG: {

                }
                break;
            }
            event = myParser.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun getPackageNameFromXml(s: String): String {
    try {
        val xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
        val myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser()
        myParser.setInput(StringReader(s))
        var event = myParser.eventType
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            val name = myParser.name
            when (event) {
                XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> {
                    if (name.toLowerCase() == "manifest") {
                        val packageName = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "package")
                        if (packageName != null) {
                            return packageName
                        }
                    }
                }

                XmlPullParser.END_TAG -> {

                    }
            }
            event = myParser.next()
        }
    } catch (e: XmlPullParserException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return ""
}
```

just call this method like below

```
textView2.setText(getPackageNameFromXml(textView1.getText().toString()))
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BqH.png)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Muzammil finally I got the answer may Allah bless you again thanks a lot I'm really so happy Assalamualaikum

Answer (score 0):

Use getText() for above task :

> String value = textView2.getText().toString();
>
> textView1.setText(value);

and for get packagename  use

> BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

for example :

textView1.setText(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

String value= textView1.getText().toString();
textView2.setText(value);

Comment: But it will set textview2 to textview1 and what I want is to take just the package name

Comment: Actually I don't need application id I know the textview1 looks like Android Manifest but it's not and what I want is to just take the package name from textview1 and show it in textview2 it's like parsing an xml file.please help me

Answer (score 0):

you textview contain xml you can parse that xml and retrieve your needing property, you can see how to parse xml text from this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm)

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: Next time you can edit your first answer instead of writing new answer